# Overwrite file_directory_temp function without touching the core?

Tags: 7, files

I need to modify the `file_directory_temp()` function, but I can't touch the core.

My drupal-site runs in Microsoft Azure Cloud and I need to exclude all temp files from drupal-root into a absolute location.

I basically want to prefix the value from `variable_get('file_temporary_path')` with an absolute file-path: `"C:\temp" + "\sites\default\tmp"`

Because the absolute part of the path is a dynamic value, which depends on environment and is returned by function `Microsoft_WindowsAzure_RoleEnvironment::getLocalResource('Temp')` it can't be stored in database, due to changing enviroment.

**In a nutshell:**

I need `file_directory_temp()` function to return:

```
$temporary_directory = Microsoft_WindowsAzure_RoleEnvironment::getLocalResource('Temp') . variable_get('file_temporary_path', NULL);
```

instead of:

```
$temporary_directory = variable_get('file_temporary_path', NULL);
```

The prefix is dynamic and can't be stored in database, due to changing enviroment setup.

Comment: If the variable containing the path is dynamic, you'll either need to patch `file_directory_temp()` or `variable_get()`, I don't see any way around that

Comment: @Clive I do, but I need a bit of help with my answer. BTW your comment inspired it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for variable_get() is:

```
function variable_get($name, $default = NULL) {
  global $conf;
  return isset($conf[$name]) ? $conf[$name] : $default;
}
```

So **if value is constant during one page call** you need to set:

```
global $conf;
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = Microsoft_WindowsAzure_RoleEnvironment::getLocalResource('Temp') . $conf['file_temporary_path'];
```

**If value can change for each request**, you need a more bold move. And  PHP 5.2.0 or later.

```
class TempClass {
  private $path;
  public function __construct($path) {
    $this->path = $path;
  }
  public function __toString() {
    return Microsoft_WindowsAzure_RoleEnvironment::getLocalResource('Temp') . $this->path;
  }
}
global $conf;
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = new TempClass($conf['file_temporary_path']);
```

That way you'll have an object, that will be converted to string on each use, and on that conversion will retrieve current value from Microsoft_WindowsAzure_RoleEnvironment class.

**Where to put it?**

Best place for it seems to be a [hook_boot()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7). You need to make sure your `hook_boot()` is called first. To get your module to run first, use [hook_module_implements_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) or easier and less reliable way - [Modules weight](https://drupal.org/project/modules_weight) module.

If you don't care about the value provided via UI, [you can (maybe should) put it in `settings.php`](https://drupal.org/node/1525472) instead, and substitute reads from $conf['file_temporary_path'] with hard-coded value. You don't need to use `global` in `settings.php`.

**Conflict with UI**

When you open form to edit `file_temporary_path`, you will see value with Azure's prefix string already prepended. That's not what you want there, as multiple saves would prepend it multiple times. Use `hook_form_alter()` to change default value to one obtained directly from the database, or, if you hardcoded it in `settings.php`, to set it to hardcoded string and disable field.