# How to debug merge query?

Tags: 7, database, debugging

I have a simple merge query, with one key and three fields, something like:

```
$query = db_merge('product')
->key(array(
  'id' => $id_product,
))
->fields(array(
  'name'   => $form_state['values']['name'],
  'symbol' => $form_state['values']['symbol'],
  'weight' => $form_state['values']['weight'],
));
```

Usually it works all right, but some combinations of data passed to it and data already in database cause me headache. I'm sure I would be able to know what's wrong and why, if only I could grab actual SQL query that goes to my database.

Usually I would do:

```
  kpr((string)$query);
```

It works well for insert for example, because insert has [`__toString()` well implemented](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/InsertQuery%3a%3a__toString/7). Sadly, implementation of [`MergeQuery::__toString`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/MergeQuery%3a%3a__toString/7) is somewhat nonexistent:

```
public function __toString() {
}
```

It isn't even a proper implementation of this magic method, as it should always return string, but OK, I can assume it was on purpose. Anyway, this changes nothing: I can't simply cast it to see it.

What other options do I have, to see queries generated by `db_merge()` / `MergeQuery` for database interaction debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `MergeQuery` just runs a `SELECT` and `INSERT` internally - there isn't a single query string available, so the `__toString()` method doesn't make sense (which is probably why it's short-circuited).

`SelectQuery` and `InsertQuery` both implement `__toString()` fully, so your best bet for debugging would be to temporarily add some code to [`MergeQuery::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/MergeQuery%3a%3aexecute/7) to dump the `$select` and/or `$insert` query before they're run, so you can inspect the query string.

Comment: It seems it's working. I would prefer to avoid hacking core, but for now it's good enough.

Comment: Problem is that `InsertQuery` doesn't invoke an alter hook. You could subclass a bunch of database classes and provide your own debuggable implementation of the relevant methods, but it seems overkill for one-time debugging

Comment: I fully agree... It worked and was straightforward enough, yet I feel reluctant to accept hacking core as an answer. I mean, upvoted of course, but I'll leave it unaccepted for now, in hope of attracting non-hackish answers.

Comment: @Mołot Temporary debug code is hardly 'hacking core'; logically the only solution without changing core files is to replace the database class with your own (quite a bit of work). I'm not sure another solution is physically possible, looking at the code (but yeah, of course, don't accept this if you're not happy with it :)

Comment: I have seen disastrous results of "temporary debug", when person who debugged accidentally "cleaned up" one line too much... I'm not sure if it's possible to do it any other way. But [hooking `variable_set()` without hacking core](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87177/16495) seemed impossible, too, and yet it wasn't even that hard, it only needed one nice spark of craziness ;)

Comment: Yep, writing code is, as always, only as good as the developer who writes and maintains it! (anyway, that's what patch files are for ;) Don't get me wrong, I hope you do get a non 'hackish' answer - I just can't see what that would be beyond subclassing what's already there. The `variable_set` override only works because of a fluke of bad design (all variables being in a globally available array). The DB classes are built with much better practice in mind, so there aren't any 'hole's...at least not that I can see

Comment: @Mołot I'm with Clive on this one.  Unless you want to break out xdebug, adding some `dpm()` to core is perfectly acceptable as long as it really is temporary, and if there aren't good alternates.  And proper revision control (especially git) make it really each to back out you changes when you are done.

Comment: @MPD Yea, I guess you both are right. And I did set up my dev environment in a way that uses git as main way of pushing changes to test server, so it's pretty hard *not* to git one's changes, even if someone does not want to. So I have this part covered. I accept the fact... but I don't have to like it :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I realise that this is going against the principle of OOP however...

```
function debug_merge_query($query, $show_placeholder_values = false) {

  // Unprotect object.
  $query_arr = (array) $query;
  $query_str = json_encode($query_arr);
  $query_str = str_replace('\u0000*\u0000', '', $query_str);
  $query_arr = (array) json_decode($query_str);
  //pdie($query_arr);

  if(!isset($query_arr['table'])) {
    drupal_set_message('You cannot execute a merge query whilst it is being debugged.');
    return false;
  }

  // Extract variables
  $table = $query_arr['table'];
  $fields = array();
  $first = true;
  foreach($query_arr['insertFields'] as $k => $v) {
    if($first) {
      $condition_key = $k;
      $condition_val = $v;
      $first = false;
    } else {
      $fields[$k] = $v;
    }
  }

  // Build select query.
  $select_query = db_select($table, $table)
    ->condition($condition_key, $condition_val);
  $select_query->addExpression('1', 'expression');

  if($show_placeholder_values) {
    dpq($select_query);
  } else {
    dpm((string)$select_query);
  }

  $row_exists = $select_query->execute()->fetchField();

  if($row_exists) {
    // Build update query.
    $update_query = db_update($table)
      ->fields($fields)
      ->condition($condition_key, $condition_val);

    $update_query_str = dpq($update_query, TRUE);

    if($show_placeholder_values) {
      $update_query_str = replace_placeholders($update_query_str, $fields);
    }

    dpm($update_query_str);

  } else {
    // Build insert query.
    $fields[$condition_key] = $condition_val;
    $insert_query = db_insert($table)
      ->fields($fields);
    $insert_query->preExecute();

    $insert_query_str = (string) $insert_query;

    if($show_placeholder_values) {
      $insert_query_str = replace_placeholders($insert_query_str, $fields);
    }

    dpm($insert_query_str);

  }

}

function replace_placeholders($query, $values) {
  $x = 0;
  foreach($values as $k => $v) {
    $replace = is_numeric($v) ? $v : '"'.$v.'"';
    $query = str_replace(':db_insert_placeholder_'.$x, $replace, $query);
    $query = str_replace(':db_update_placeholder_'.$x, $replace, $query);
    $x++;
  }
  return $query;
}
```

So to test this function you can use the following code:

```
$id_product = 1;

$query = db_merge('product')
  ->key(array(
    'id' => $id_product,
  ))
  ->fields(array(
    'name'   => 'test',
    'symbol' => 'apple',
    'weight' => 12,
  ))
  //->execute()
  ;

debug_merge_query($query, true);
```

Comment: I think this proves my point - a patch to core is far better than reproducing all this code in procedural functions :)